# enabling MPLS,RSVP and OSPF-TE

Tags: juniper, traffic-shaping, ospf, junos, mpls

I am using Juniper J-series routers to emulate a small telco and VPN customer.I need to use OSPF so that the routing information can be propagated to all P and PE nodes (basically all core and edge routers).Note that I don't want the routing information to be propogated to the customer facing routers (the green ones.)

### TAU-PE1:

```
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface ge-0/0/0
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface ge-0/0/1

set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface lo0.0 passive (loopback)
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface ge-0/0/2.0 passive (customer facing)
```

### HAM-PE1:

```
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface ge-0/0/0

set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface lo0.0 passive (loopback)
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface ge-0/0/2.0 passive (customer facing)
```

### TAU-P1:

```
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface ge-0/0/0
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface ge-0/0/1
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface ge-0/0/2

set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface lo0.0 passive (loopback)
```

### ACK-P1:

```
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface ge-0/0/0
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface ge-0/0/2
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface ge-0/0/3

set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface lo0.0 passive (loopback)
```

### HAM-P1:

```
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface ge-0/0/0
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface ge-0/0/1
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface ge-0/0/3

set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface lo0.0 passive (loopback)
```

Now I want to enable the following things on all PE and P nodes.

1) MPLS
2) RSVP
3) OSPF-TE extension

### As an example on TAU-P1

```
set protocols mpls interface ge-0/0/0
set protocols mpls interface ge-0/0/1
set protocols mpls interface ge-0/0/2

set protocols rsvp interface ge-0/0/0
set protocols rsvp interface ge-0/0/1
set protocols rsvp interface ge-0/0/2

set protocols ospf traffic-engineering interface ge-0/0/0 
set protocols ospf traffic-engineering interface ge-0/0/1
set protocols ospf traffic-engineering interface ge-0/0/2
```

Are the below steps sufficient to achieve the above? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You generally shouldn't be deleting and re-creating your questions, when a simple modification of the original question would be enough.  If you delete/recreate your question too many times the system automatically bans you from asking new questions.

Comment: I was not getting any responses for the previous question.I could have edited out the irrelevant details.thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Do a Google search for JunOS enterprise router, its easily found in PDF form and will answer almost all your questions about OSPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two configuration statements you've included will tell a JunOS device to do two things:

1) Start transmitting link state advertisements on that interface.

2) Advertise the subnets configured on those interfaces.

For each device, you should be using the command:

```
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface lo0.0 passive
```

The passive option tells JunOS to include that subnet, but do not send advertisements down that link. You almost always do this on loopback interfaces. If an interface is not facing another router you wish to distribute routes to, then that interface should be set as passive.

So, you should be adding this statement to UOW-TAU and UOW-HAM:

```
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface ge-0/0/1.0 passive
```

On TAU-PE1 and HAM-PE1, you can receive the advertisements by adding the statement:

```
set protocols ospf area 0.0.0.0 interface ge-0/0/2.0
```